# How to remove the gap between to widgets in a column?

Tags: flutter, widget, padding, margin

I have a `Column` with two `Container`s. There is no padding, no margin.
The sizes perfectly fit together.
But still, I got this subpixel gap between widgets. It is visible on the simulator and real device.

[image: gap]

My code below:

```
       Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 57.0.h(context),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) => Column( // the column I actually am worried about
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * .45,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          // here's some code
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * .55,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          // here's some code
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                // here's some code
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I've tried to make Container below `Expanded` (so to occupy ALL the remaining space) but nothing has changed.

Comment: It might be that the children are applying a default padding in them, would you also show the children?

Comment: I have the same issue, any progress on this?

Comment: @Cristi propably a bit late, but I found a solution, see my answer. Maybe it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Wrapping each widget in a container with a 0-pixel border of the desired color did the trick:

```dart
    Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 0.0,
            color: /* same Color that your widget has */,
          ),
          color: /* same Color that your widget has */,
        ),
        child: // child widget goes here
    )
```

The issue is propably caused because of the anti-aliasing behavior, as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17084).

I think this solves the problem because the color of the border is used for anti-aliasing edges that are not aligned with hardware pixels. But that's just my theory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Container`'s `decoration` with  zero border width.

```dart
Container(
  height: constraints.maxHeight * .45,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    border: Border.all(
      // one or both
      color: Colors.transparent,
      width: 0.0,
    ),
  ),
.....
```

Comment: nope, unfortunately still the same

Comment: is it possible you are not providing full height, Can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app. and can you provide full sample widget without depending on others variables that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: after cleaning nothing has changed.. it is somehow not about external variables and height params as I create in the middle of a screen purely new Column with two Containers of the same color and see this gap anyway.. so no specifics to the position or dimention so far

Comment: Can you provide simplify version of it that will reproduce, You can check about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)